# Javascript function is not working when called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm creating a function that checks id values for 0 or 1. This function is to perform following task (Triggering SMS function):

1) If on page load, value of any id is 1(true), this function will not allow sms trigger for this id, but if value goes to 0(false) and again returns to 1(true) it will trigger a sms function.

2) If on page load, value of id is 0(false), this function will allow SMS triggering if its value changes to 1 (true) any time.

Note: When I check this function with `value1` or `value2`or `value3` separately it is working fine. But when I execute this funciton for multiple ids like `onloadcheck(value1); onloadcheck(value2);` it creates problem. No error but not working in proper manner.

Please help me. Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function() {
rand_val();
}, 1000);   

});


//check initial values of all ids 


var onloadcheck = (function() {
    var executed = false;
    var enableit = false;
    return function(x) {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            if(x==1){enableit = false;}
            if(x==0){enableit = true;}
        }
        if(x==1 && enableit ){
        console.log("Sending SMS");
        enableit = false;
        }
        if(x==0 ){
        enableit = true;
        }
    };
})();






//generates random values 
function rand_val(){
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
var value1= $("#demo1").text();

document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
var value2= $("#demo2").text();


document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
var value3= $("#demo3").text();

onloadcheck(value1);
onloadcheck(value2);


}
```

Here is HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test SMS</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

        <p>Test SMS Triggers</p>

        <p id="demo1"></p>
        <p id="demo2"></p>
        <p id="demo3"></p>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code.

Comment: `if(x==1 && enablesms ){` did you mean `enableit` to go here? As i don't see a `enablesms` elsewhere in your code

Comment: Yes please. I forgot it to update before posting.

Comment: Define "not working", "creates problem," and "not working in the proper manner." How does the result differ from your expectations?

Comment: Sorry for bad english that you found it difficult to understand.  TJBlackman gave the solution that working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is difficult is because you need to get their current value and compare it with their previous value. So to do that, you need to always store a copy of their previous value.

In my example, I store a copy of their previous value in an object, then each time there is an update, I get the old value from my object, the new value from the element, and compare the two. Then don't forget to save the new value in your object!!

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e8jt4mmk/6/)

```
<p id="demo1">1</p>
<p id="demo2">0</p>
<p id="demo3">0</p>

<button type="button">Update &amp; Re-Check Values</button>

<script>
// cache DOM elements for quick reference
var demo1 = $('#demo1');
var demo2 = $('#demo2');
var demo3 = $('#demo3');

// store their current values in object
// this is how we will reference their previous values in the future
var stored_values = {
  demo1: demo1.text(),
  demo2: demo2.text(),
  demo3: demo3.text()
}; 


// loop through all elements
// get their current value from .text()
// get their PREVIOUS value from the object we made above
// compare values with our custom compare function (define below)
// finally, save the current value in our object
function checkValues(){
    [demo1, demo2, demo3].forEach(function(item){
    var element_id = item.attr('id');
    var currentValue = item.text(); 
    var previousValue = stored_values[element_id];
        compareValues(currentValue, previousValue, element_id);
    stored_values[element_id] = currentValue; 
  });
}


// compare values passed in, and determine what to do
function compareValues(current, previous, elementID){
    if (previous == 0 && current == 1){
    alert('Sending SMS for '+ elementID + '!!!');
  } else {
    return; // do nothing
  }
}


// on button click
// assign new value, then checkValue()
$('button').click(function(){
    $('p').each(function(index, element){
        var number = Math.round(Math.random()); 
    $(element).text(number); 
  });
  checkValues(); 
});
</script>
```